# Full text search feature not available from installation wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have sql server 2008 R2 Express installed, but it seems the full text search feature hasn't been installed. So after reading up on it in dozens of forums I concluded that it can be added by running the installer again and just adding the feature to the already existing installation. So I downloaded the installation executable called SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 64 bit W/Tools from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

The file name is SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe. When I run it, it correctly starts up the installation software. I then click on "*New Installation or add features to an existing installation*" which starts the wizard. However when I get to the features section it doesn't offer the Full-text-search feature as so many forums are suggesting it should. Could someone please clarify for me how I can get this feature added? It says on the Microsoft website that SQL server express "Offers reporting capabilities, full-text search, and spatial support", so I know it's not a version issue.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the version with the so called advanced services for fulltext search with express.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25174

Comment: That's it! I was looking everywhere for this! Thank you very much

Comment: The link in the answer is now not reachable. Try this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/details.aspx?id=101064